# How can I use Bower to pull in only the files I want? (e.g. just the .js file, no docs, tests, etc)

Tags: laravel-4, assets, assetic

I'm using bower to pull in css and js libraries that I'm using but I've bumped into a little bit of trouble when it comes to consistency. But first a little on my asset pipeline management:

I'm using laravel's asset pipeline package which looks in specific directories for the appropriate .js/.css files and minifies it in production. So I need `myapp/lib/javascripts/` to store all only `jquery.js, angular.js, foundation.js`. Same for my .css as well.

Currently I've been copying it over manually, but I want to be able to automate this on a single `bower update`. Is this possible with the tools I use currently (laravel or bower)?

Different vendors have inconsistent folder structures (e.g. `typeahead/dist/typeahead.bundle.js`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: you don't use Bower for that.

Bower is a package manager and will grab the distribution as the author defines it. You can define the location where it saves the packages but not cherry pick individual files.

You are missing a build manager / build script that can (among other things) copy files from one location to another. By far the most popular are [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).

I would highly recommend taking the time to learn and integrate one of these tools into your workflow.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of these tools but I'm on a tight time constraint and the less tools I chain together for project to work the better. I have started writing an artisan command that uses `bower update` and specified folder directories to move things where I need them.

Comment: Understood. I think you can get something working with Grunt in under an hour. However the answer to your question is still "you can't do that with Bower" :)